# HTML - Continue Ordered List after table

Tags: html, list, continue

Here is my example of what I am trying to do. I have a list before my table and I need it to continues after the table where it left off. I found the code  which works in IE but Dreamweaver seems to ignore it and just places bullets. I read that this ol.continue is XML which I think may be the problem. My Question, is there a way to get Dreamweaver to recognize it or is there another code I might use? I've looked everywhere and this is the only code I could find.

Thanks

```
<ol start="1">
  <li>
    Line 1
  </li>

  <li>
    Line 2
  </li>
</ol>

<Table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Some Text
    </td>
  </tr>
</Table>

<ol.continue>
  <li>
    Line 3
  </li>

  <li>
    Line 4
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: `<ol start="10"> </ol>` & `ol { list-style-type: decimal; }`

Comment: sometimes the things we want are not sensible, yet we cling to it. think more and you will find a better way of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

As @mdesdev said, use:

```
<ol start="7">
```

I didn't see his answer and found it from here:

[The ol Element and Related Attributes: type, start, value, and reversed](http://html5doctor.com/ol-element-attributes/)